# Payment Gateway Integration With Custom Screen and API

Tags: php, android, ios, payment-gateway, braintree

I want to integrate Braintree into my project. But I have following issues:-

I want recurring payment in sdks, which is not possible as per Braintree documentations. For this my company wants me to develop a custom screen which will take card details and that I need to send on server and my server will make payment also create recurring profile in Braintree as Braintree provides recurring in web.

So, If I do so, what it will be a risk of app to get rejected in apple review because of custom payment screen ?

Answer (score 0):

According to [Braintree's developer documentation](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/drop-in/overview/ios/v4#key-features):

> If the Drop-in UI doesn't fit your needs, develop your own custom
>   integration using our [client SDKs](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/client-sdk/setup/android/v2) to accept [credit cards](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/credit-cards/overview),
>   [PayPal](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/paypal/overview/android/v2), and other available payment method types. This allows you
>   full control over the checkout process. Using our native mobile SDKs,
>   you can typically qualify for the SAQ A PCI compliance form with a
>   custom integration

Comment: Thank You for your answer, But could you please tell me , If I dont use sdk and create custom screen and hit my api to make payments, then would it be risk to get rejected in apple / google review ?

Comment: Listen @Nitin if you are integrating payment gateway in android or ios then there is two options one is Seamless payment gateway integration  and another is non- seamless payment gateway integration for more detail of seamless and non-seamless read this link you will get idea..https://www.quora.com/What-is-difference-between-Seamless-and-Non-Seamless-integration-of-a-Payment-Gateway.